# Flutter image package copyCrop results in rotated image

Tags: flutter, image, android-camera

I'm trying to capture and save a cropped imaged.
Im using image: ^3.3.0
This is the code:

```
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;

class CaptureCameraWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  CaptureCameraWidget({super.key});
  static const routeName = 'home-screen';
  late img.Image cropped;
  bool? loaded = false;
  bool showCamera = false;
  @override
  _CaptureCameraWidgetState createState() => _CaptureCameraWidgetState();
}

class _CaptureCameraWidgetState extends State<CaptureCameraWidget> {
  late Image imgController;
  bool loaded = false;
  late CameraController controller;

  GlobalKey _keyWidth = GlobalKey();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: initializationCamera(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return Container(
            height: size.height * 0.9,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
              top: 5,
            ),
            child: Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              children: [
                Container(
                    height: size.height * 0.9 - 100,
                    child: Transform.scale(
                              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                              scale: 1 /
                                  (controller.value.aspectRatio *
                                      MediaQuery.of(context).size.aspectRatio),
                              child: CameraPreview(controller)),),
                Container(
                  height: size.height * 0.9 - 100,
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                          key: _keyWidth,
                          child:
                              Container(color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.6))),
                      Container(
                        height: size.height * 0.9 - 100,
                        child: Image.asset(
                          'assets/camera-overlay-conceptcoder.png',
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                          child:
                              Container(color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.6))),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  bottom: 0,
                  child: Container(
                    width: size.width - 100,
                    child: Stack(
                      children: [
                        ClickWithSpin(
                          onClicked: onTakePicture,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  left: 0,
                  bottom: 0,
                  child: InkWell(
                    onTap: () {},
                    child: const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0),
                      child: CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 30.0,
                          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                          child: Icon(Icons.close, color: Colors.black)),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }

  Future<void> initializationCamera() async {
    var cameras = await availableCameras();
    controller = CameraController(
      cameras[0],
      ResolutionPreset.medium,
      imageFormatGroup: ImageFormatGroup.yuv420,
    );
    await controller.initialize();
  }

  void onTakePicture() async {
    // TCardController().onTimeRun();
    // return;
    await controller.takePicture().then((XFile xfile) async {
      if (mounted) {
        Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
        if (xfile != null) {
          final bytes = await xfile.readAsBytes();
          //   final image = img.decodeImage(bytes);
          final RenderBox renderBox =
              _keyWidth.currentContext?.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
          double widthh = size.width - 3 * (renderBox.size.width + 10);
          File? cr = await cropImage(xfile.path,
              1.5 * (renderBox.size.width + 10), 20, widthh, widthh * 1.6);
          showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (_) {
                // return object of type Dialog

                return AlertDialog(
                  title: Image.file(File(cr!.path)),
                );
              });
        }
      }
    });
  }
}

Future<File?> cropImage(
    String imagePath, double x, double y, double width, double height) async {
  // Read the image file
  final File imageFile = File(imagePath);
  Uint8List uint8List;
  final List<int> imageBytes = await imageFile.readAsBytes();
  uint8List = Uint8List.fromList(imageBytes);
  final img.Image? image = img.decodeImage(imageBytes);
  if (image != null) {
    final int left = (x).round();
    final int top = (y).round();
    final int cropWidth = (width).round();
    final int cropHeight = (height).round();
    final img.Image croppedImage =
        img.copyCrop(image, left, top, cropWidth, cropHeight);
    final croppedFile = File('${imagePath}_croppe.png');

    return croppedFile.writeAsBytes(img.encodePng(croppedImage));
    
  }
  return null;
}

class ClickWithSpin extends StatefulWidget {
  ClickWithSpin({required this.onClicked, super.key});
  bool showSpin = false;
  Function() onClicked;
  @override
  State<ClickWithSpin> createState() => _ClickWithSpinState();
}

class _ClickWithSpinState extends State<ClickWithSpin> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.showSpin == true
        ? const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          )
        : Center(
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                widget.onClicked();
                setState(() {
                  widget.showSpin = true;
                });
              },
              child: const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
                child: CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 50.0,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                    child:
                        Icon(Icons.camera_alt_outlined, color: Colors.white)),
              ),
            ),
          );
  }
}
```

This is how the screen looks like:
[image]

This is an example of an image, captured by the camera:
[image]

And this is what I get after cropping:
[image: As you can see, the image is not cropped in the correct position and it is also rotated]

The values inside cropImage are: 70, 20, 300, 480

I can't figure out what is going on here?
Does anyone have an idea?